# How do I fill a shape with text, like a circle?

Tags: formatting, shapepar

How do I confine text within a shape such as a circle or triangle?  I don't want text along the perimeter, I would like it to break appropriately at all the inner edges.

Answer (score 19):

Look at `shapepar` [(manual)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) for how to do it.

Comment: Neat! Looks much better than trying to use `\parshape`.

Comment: Also, the `shapepatch` package could be useful, if one finds defining shapes complicated. It allows using `xfig` shapes to describe the boundaries, if that's your thing.

Comment: @Martin: make this an answer instead of a comment and you can receive some upvotes for it.

Comment: @Mattew: one can still upvote a comment...if you think it is deserving. This should be devorced from Martin's decision on writing his own answer, ofcourse.

Comment: @Yossi @Matthew I decided to add a comment here because it felt wrong to post essentially what Yossi said with little additional information. I squeezed in some minutes just today to write an answer with an example, which I believe is a significant  improvement. I couldn't care less for some "easy" 20-30 rep, I try to make my answers informative and useful instead.

Comment: @martin: I think your answer is great! much better than mine. Mine is way to short (I was lazy)...thanks for taking the time for writing a nice illustrative example. I don't think it is wrong at all to write an answer that combines two partial answers into one. I would go so far and ask that the user1161 might want to reconsider what he marked as the "answer" because I think that yours is a much more complete one.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: what link is dead?

Answer (score 18):

As @Yossi mentioned before, `shapepar` is your friend. The full documentation is at its [usual place](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) in CTAN. Here's an example how to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\begin{document}

\def\triangledownshape{%
{0}%
{0}b{0}\\%
{0}t{-10}{20}\\%
{8.66}t{-5}{10}\\%
{17.32}e{0}%
}
\def\triangledownpar#1{\Shapepar\triangledownshape #1\unskip\ $\bigtriangledown$\par}

\triangledownpar{This is an example of a shape created with 
   \texttt{shapepar}. Other predefined possibilities include \textbf{circle},     
   \textbf{donut}, \textbf{heart}, \textbf{star}, \textbf{star}, \textbf{nut}, 
   \textbf{rectangle}. Also, there are other definitions currently not included 
   by default, which you'd find in the \texttt{*shapes.def} files in the
   \texttt{shapepar} directory~--- \textbf{drops}, \textbf{triangles} (facing all 
   directions), \textbf{\TeX logo}, \textbf{candle}, \textbf{Canadian flag}. 
   Your result may or may not look weird, depending on the size of the shape
   and the word distribution.}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like the following image (example uses `\documentclass{standalone}`, to preserve space):

[image: triangle example]

A simple circle example:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\begin{document}
\Shapepar{\circleshape} I see now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do.\par
\end{document}
```

[image: circle example]

Cutouts with custom shapes are also possible, but I haven't tried that in this particular example.

Personally, I find defining new shapes not very straight-forward, but YMMV. Also, if you're into `xfig` (I'm not), you could try the `shapepatch` package which basically patches (duh!) the `xfig` package so that you could use your masterpiece as a boundary for `shapepar`. I can't comment how well this works, though -- I've never used it.